# How to access youtube data api json response $t variable in php?

Tags: php, api, youtube

I'm getting a JSON response from the YouTube Data API.

Here is a sample response of the Title variable:

stdClass Object
(
    [$t] => Video Title
)

How do I access the $t variable?

$blah->$t won't work because it looks for a variable by $t, and not a member of $blah with name $t.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$blah->{'$t'}
```

message to avoid SO message length limit ;)